# htop shows lower memory consumption than free -h or top

Tags: memory, ram, htop

I have a laptop with Artix Linux installed. When I check my RAM usage using htop, it shows significantly lower memory usage than free -h. Here's an example:

htop:

```
Mem[|||||||||||||         1.45G/7.60G]
```

```
$ free -h | grep -E 'Mem:|total'
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6Gi       2.0Gi       5.1Gi       335Mi       1.0Gi       5.6Gi
```

Swap is empty most of the time:

`Swp[                 0K/8.01G]`

`Swap:          8.0Gi          0B       8.0Gi`

And yes, I do see that they use different measurement units; however, 2.0 Gi would actually translate into 2.1 G. The difference between values is changing, too; if I have a freshly booted system, then free would show double the htop's value. Also, notice how the total RAM amount is the same.

Comment: every tool defines "used memory" in its own way. Some tools ignore buffer/cache, some add it to the used space. To me it looks like, `htop` shows, what would be used + shared - buffer from `free`.   I can't confirm that theorie on my system. In my case, it looks more like `htop` is showing as used, `free` reports as used - buffer. In my case, I use `zfs`, which does not add its buffer to the "usual" buffer, but reserves it as used by application.